# calculate number in views ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to calculate mid test and final test mark into a grade. E.g.:

```
mid test = 80 , final test = 80
(midtest + finaltest)/2 >=80
grade = "A"
```

Is it possible to do an if condition in views and insert into database? Something like:

```
 if (midtest + finaltest) / 2 >= 80
      grade = "A"
    elsif (midtest + finaltest)/2 >= 70 and < 80
      grade = "B"
    elsif (midtest + finaltest) /2 >= 60 and < 70
      grade = "C"
```

So that in views we don't need a `text_field` for grades and so that the calculation is automatically inserted into the database.

**This is the solution**
**Controller**

```
def create

    @nilai = Nilai.new(params[:nilai])
    @nilai.get_grade
    respond_to do |format|
      if @nilai.save
        format.html { redirect_to @nilai, notice: 'Nilai was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @nilai, status: :created, location: @nilai }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @nilai.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end
```

Model

```
class Nilai < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :grade, :id_makul, :id_mhs, :id_nilai, :uas, :uts

  def get_grade

    @calculate = (self.uas + self.uts)/2
    if @calculate >= 80
      self.grade = "A"
      elsif @calculate >=70 and @calculate < 80
        self.grade = "B"
      elsif @calculate >=60 and @calculate <70
        self.grade = "C"
      elsif @calculate >=50 and @calculate <60
        self.grade = "D"
    else
      self.grade = "E"
    end  
  end

end
```

Comment: Yes it is possible... but it is generally considered very poor design to do data manipulation (and especially saving data into the db) in a view. Why do you think you need to do this in a view? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: it's like there are 3 text field . . mid test , final test , and grade . . what i want to solve is we don't have to insert the grade ourself . . after we input mid test and final test , the grade automaticaly has the result from the field above (mid test and final test) . . any solutions ? =D . . thanks before

Comment: what do you mean by "we don't have to insert the grade ourself ." who is "we"?

Comment: may be lecture or anyone who input data

Comment: sorry, but that isn't; enough information for me to be able to understand what you mean by "we". I think that all you want is for the person typing in the input to not have to calculate the values yourself. You'd like the model to have a method that does this, based on the values typed in for the tests. In which case, my answer below should solve your problem for you.

Comment: it works . . thanks a bunch . . i placed it in the controller . . thanks alot =D

Comment: Ok, so if an answer works for you, you need to "accept" it. This marks it as the correct answer for your problem, and lets everybody know that the problem now has a solution (this is especially useful if other people have the same problem, so they can know there is a solution). You accept an answer by moving your mouse to the left of the answer - a greyed-out "tick" will appear. Click the tick and it will turn green.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still guessing what you really want and why you think you have to do it in the view...

As I said above, Views should be used solely for code that displays data that already exists. Code that inserts things into the database is for your models and controllers.

I suggest either:

1) you create a method on your model called "grade" eg:

```
def grade
  if (midtest + finaltest) / 2 >= 80
    return "A"
  elsif (midtest + finaltest)/2 >= 70 and < 80
    return "B"
  elsif (midtest + finaltest) /2 >= 60 and < 70
    return "C"
  else
    return "F"
  end
end
```

now, you can call this method from your view eg:

```
Grade: <%=  @my_model.grade %>
```

Note that this method does not insert it into the database.

**OR**

2) you create a method as above on a `before_save` callback

eg lets say you're storing it into the "grade" column in the db:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create :calculate_grade

  def calculate_grade
    if (midtest + finaltest) / 2 >= 80
      self.grade = "A"
    elsif (midtest + finaltest)/2 >= 70 and < 80
      self.grade = "B"
    elsif (midtest + finaltest) /2 >= 60 and < 70
      self.grade = "C"
    else
      self.grade = "F"
    end
  end
end
```

And now whenever your model gets saved, the grade gets re-calculated from the test scores and saved into the db alongside.
so you can use "grade" in your views as above, but it's coming from the database column

```
Grade: <%=  @my_model.grade %>
```

Answer (score 2):

technically you could do almost anything in views, after all view is also a ruby file. So you could have conditions, DB connections etc..

BUT, Its **not a good practise** to have your logic in your views. Always try to have your view to display only. All the processing logic should be in Models

Idea is, Fat models, thin controllers are views are only for presentation. So in your case try and see at least to get your login in to a helper method.

One more thing I notice, you could have this line

```
 (midtest + finaltest) / 2
```

to

```
 average_marks = (midtest + finaltest) / 2
```

and use `average_marks`, in other places, as its more DRY (Dont Repeat Yourself)

HTH :)